# Changing Move Feature mechanism in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, toolbar

I am currently using Qgis 3.2.1 and struggle with the move feature mechanism there. Its works like a select and drop function and it´s pretty akward to use. See the picture below: (moved features will be inserted on red dot position) Using the Snapping Tool doesn't work that well with that kind of movement either.

[image]

In QGIS 2.18.5 the move feature mechanism was much better. It was without this "dropping". While moving a feature it was following the mouse cursor.
At least for me serveral times faster to work with.

Is it possible to change the move feature mechanism in QGIS 3.2.1 so that it works again like in older versions ?

Comment: As far as I am aware it is not possible to revert back to QGIS 2.x functionality - it takes a little getting used to but I actually prefer it.